# Using Linq to determine if a record does not exist in a list but does exist in a table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am having trouble determining if a record exists in the database table but not in the updated records contained within a list. If the record does not exist within the updated list but does within the database table then that record needs to deleted.

I can query the table to determine if it has been modified and if the record does not exist in the database table then update it, but determining the opposite is proving a bit more tricky. Another constraint is that I need the outcome to be a bool value of exists = true and not exist = false so that i can than handle the deleting of the record appropriately.

I am doing this to determine if the record does not exist in the database table:

```
bool exists = db.table.Any(t => t.EntityID != list.EntityID)
```

But can not seem to manage the reverse.

The list and the database table have 1 to 1 mapping using Entity Framework.

If record exists in database but not in list then delete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you've reversed the logic there.  If you want to check for the existence of a particular record, the ID of which is stored in `list.EntityID`, it looks like this:

```
bool exists = db.table.Any(t => t.EntityID == list.EntityID);
```

If you have a list of entities and you want to find any records that exist in the database that don't exist in the list you can do this:

```
var extraitems = db.table.Where(t => !list.Select(l => l.EntityID).Contains(t.EntityID));
```

That will give you a list of entities you can pass to `DeleteAllOnSubmit()`.

Comment: what if you want to find any records that "doesn't" exist in database but exist in the list?

Comment: @AnilPurswani Depends.  If the list is small and the table large `var extraitems = list.Where(l => !db.table.Select(t => t.EntityID).Contains(t.EntityID));` should do it.  If the list is large and the table is small then pulling down the IDs from the table first is probably going to be faster.

Comment: Just a quick correction on Corey's comment: the last "t.EntityID" should be "l.EntityID"  


var extraitems = list.Where(l => !db.table.Select(t => t.EntityID).Contains(t.EntityID));

Comment: @DarrynFrost the reason this works is because the query builder will take the output of `list.Select(l => l.EntityID)` and turn it into a value list in the query.  You get a fairly good result for smallish lists.  It gets terrible when the lists are large and will fail completely at some point.

Comment: @DarrynFrost Your method runs a query against the database for each row in your list.  This is very slow.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool exists = db.table.Any(t => list.EntityID.Contains(t.EntityID))
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? It is currently incomplete.